# Android (Method for finding Array repeated numbers)

Tags: java, android, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android (method for checking an arrays for repeated numbers?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762767/android-method-for-checking-an-arrays-for-repeated-numbers)

I've just asked a question and got a few answers and i was very happy to, but there were very complicated answers, I'm quite new to android so can some one maybe give me some example code or some think explained not the complicated. I've tried there code and tried to make sense of it but i cant.

here is the question....

could any one help me. i am making an app, and in the java, numbers are send to a int array and i need to check if any of the numbers in the array repeated and if there are to call a method or something like that. Is there a method to check this or something similar? or would i have to do it using loops and if statements, which i have tried but is getting a bit long and confusing. Any advice would be great, thanks.

```
int test[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; (The Array)

(A method to check if any of the arrays numbers are repeated)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the items in a Set if you do not want them to repeat. If add returns false then you have a repeating number

```
Set uniqueItems = new HashSet();
for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++)
    if(!uniqueItems.add(test[a]))
       System.out.println("The item is already in the set");
```

Answer (score 2):

First don't make double topic.
Second you are searching for a Java answer not related to Android.

I think that maybe it's better if you first learn java (or other language like).

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the array. Then search through the array comparing each node to the node on either of it's sides. Or you could store the data in a Set which cannot have duplicates.

Comment: In runtime i want to see if there are any numbers repeated in an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList(test).contains(valueYouWantCheck).
```

If you want to find out for each and every value in test array, Yes I think you need to loop the array.